# Django Query: How to find all posts from people you follow

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, django-queryset

I'm currently building a website with the Django Framework. I want on the homepage of my website to display all posts made by people the user is following. Here are the classes for Profile, Story and Follow:

```
class Profile(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
   email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
   last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)

class Follow(models.Model):
   following = models.ForeignKey('Profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="following")
   follower = models.ForeignKey('Profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="follower")
   follow_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Story(models.Model):
   author = models.ForeignKey('accounts.Profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="author")
   title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   content = models.TextField(max_length=10000)
```

As you can see Follow uses two Foreign Keys to represent the following and the follower. Is there a way to query all stories from people the user is following?

I really don't know what to filter. Or is this maybe a job for aggregation? If someone could help me, that would be awesome!

```
following_feed = Story.object.filter(???).order_by('-creation_date')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One can use *double* underscores (`__`) to look "through" relations (like `ForeignKey`s, etc.).

So here we can filter like:

```
Story.objects.filter(
    author__following__follower=my_profile
)
```

So by using `author` we obtain a reference to the `Profile` of the author, then with `following` we look at the `Follow` model and then finally with `follower` we again obtain a reference to `Profile`(s): the profile(s) of the follower(s).

`my_profile` of course need to be substituted with a `Profile` object (the profile of the person that is a `follower` of the `author`s of the `Story`s you wish to obtain).

This will generate a query like:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM story AS s
JOIN follow AS f ON f.following_id = s.author_id
WHERE f.follower_id = 123
```

where `123` is the `id` of the `my_profile`.

If a person is following another person multiple times (here this can happen since you do not enforce that the `follower, following` tuples are unique in the `Follow` model), then the corresponding `Story`s will be yielded *multiple* times.

It is therefore probably better to add a `unique_together` constraint in the `Follow` model:

```
class Follow(models.Model):
    following = models.ForeignKey(
        'Profile',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="following"
    )
    follower = models.ForeignKey(
        'Profile',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="follower"
    )
    follow_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('following', 'follower'), )
```

It might also be worth to see the `Follow` model as the `through` model of a [**`ManyToManyField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).

Comment: And how would I go about finding the Profile object of the currently authenticated user?

Comment: @FrederikVanclooster: with `request.user` you obtain the user model (this is by default a `User` model, although you can change that). If you did not set it to `Profile`, then you will need to follow a `ForeignKey` you have set between `User` and `Profile`, or perform a lookup, etc. based on matching data (like email adresses), although the latter is data duplication, and thus a severe anti-pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Note that I haven't tested the code I am posting so tell me if something is missing. 
First, you need to get all the `Profiles` that your users follow. Then you have to get the `Stories` that they have.

```
followed_people = Follow.objects.filter(follower=current_user).values('following')
stories = Story.objects.filter(author__in=followed_people)
```